# Kubernetes: Only one service endpoint working

Tags: kubernetes, service, endpoint

I've deployed my Django/React app into K8s and exposed both deployments as a service (ClusterIP).
Whenever I try to call the API service through its ClusterIP:8000, it sometimes refuses the connection. So I checked its endpoints and only one out of the three existing endpoints returns what I expect. I understand that when calling the ClusterIP, it redirects to one of those three endpoints.

Is there any way to 'debug' a incoming service request? Can I modify the amount of existing endpoints (so I could limit it to the only working endpoint)? Is there any other way to maybe see logs of the service to find out why only one of the endpoints is working?

Comment: You can modify the amount of existing endpoints, that's covered [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors), you should be able to create endpoint service for your deployment service and use that ip and port. About the failing endpoints, could you tell me something more about your cluster? Is that cluster on-premis like  minikube or kubeadm?  Could you add your deployment and service yamls?

Comment: This is the yaml for the deployment: https://pastebin.com/wEEWyTVp
To expose it, I used "kubectl expose deployment/customer-api-deployment" and those three endpoints were created automatically. 

To install the cluster I used kubeadm. Within the cluster I have a namespace with a DB, API and Web pod. The incoming request (through external LB) is processed in the web pod and from there I want to make API calls within the same namespace to the api pod (exposed as written above).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix it:

I deployed a three-tier-application (Django/React/DB) and used the same selector for every deployment, like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp-xxx-deployment
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
```

So when exposing this with `"kubectl expose deployment/..."` it created as many endpoints as equal selectors were found in the deployment. Since I have three deployments (DB/React/Djagno), three endpoints were created.

Changing the deployment .yaml like this fixed my error and only one endpoint was crated:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: myapp-web
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mapp-web
```

Answer (score 0):

ClusterIP:8000 is not seems right to use.
You could replace it to http://$(serviceName).$(namespace):8000/ for using service correctly.

Comment: I just wanted to point out with that, that I exposed the deployment as type ClusterIP. Calling the service with the FQDN is giving me the same error. It seems that the service itself isn't the problem. It's always only one endpoint responding.